# Can we get mullet.stackexchange.com aliased to dba.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

In line with [@gbn's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/630/gbn) status as an unofficial dba.se mascot, would it be possible to get mullet.stackexchange.com aliased to dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/35v8in/